# C# Include "static" (undeletable/unalterable) text in text field (ComboBox/Textbox)

Tags: c#, text, combobox, textbox, readonly

I have been trying to make a custom TextBox component that would allow me to include a static bit of text included in the TextBox's input field, and consequently, disallowing the user to alter it.

I have figured out that I would have to manipulate/hook the key input events (including WndProc).

Concretely, my goal is to prevent the user from paste-replacing, cutting, deleting a static piece of text that can be be either "docked" (or not) to the start or end of the TextBox.

I have tried many things, but the issue that I was constantly facing was that I couldn't deduce the end position of the selection.

What I currently have (inspired/based on [TNumEditBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29766/TNumEditBox-A-Numeric-Edit-Control-with-ContextMen)):

```
public class LibraryComboBox : HybridComboBox //Ignore the parent class' name; it is basically a ComboBox that supports the ReadOnly attribute
{
    public LibraryComboBox()
        : base()
    { }

    public String SelectedLibrary { get; set; } //Static text
    public TextPosition TextPosition = TextPosition.None; //"Docking" position

    private const int WM_CHAR = 0x0102;
    private const int WM_CUT = 0x0300;
    private const int WM_COPY = 0x0301;
    private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;
    private const int WM_CLEAR = 0x0303;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_PASTE)
        {
            //TODO: Prevent overwriting the static part
        }
        else if (m.Msg == WM_CUT)
        {
            //TODO: Prevent cutting over the static part
        }
        else if (m.Msg == WM_CLEAR)
        {
            base.OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys)Shortcut.CtrlV)
        {

            string text = Clipboard.GetText();

            for (int k = 0; k < text.Length; k++)
            {
                SendCharKey(text[k]);
            }
            return true;
        }
        else if (keyData == (Keys)Shortcut.CtrlC)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(this.SelectedText);
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);

        if (!this.ReadOnly)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Delete || e.KeyData == Keys.Back)
            {
                //TODO: Remove corresponding characters
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;  // does not transform event to KeyPress, but to KeyUp
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);

        if (this.ReadOnly)
        {
            return;
        }

        //TODO: Prevent any unauthorized changes to the library path

        if (this.SelectionStart < this.Text.IndexOf(this.SelectedLibrary))
            e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void SendCharKey(char c)
    {
        Message msg = new Message();

        msg.HWnd = this.Handle;
        msg.Msg = WM_CHAR;
        msg.WParam = (IntPtr)c;
        msg.LParam = IntPtr.Zero;

        base.WndProc(ref msg);
    }
}

public enum TextPosition
{
    None = 0,
    Left = 1,
    Right = 2
}
```

Comment: So you want a text field where you can edit part of it, but not the rest? Why not just have two separate text boxes?

Comment: Because I want it to be flexible, the text can either be located to the right or left or just float there in the "middle", which can not be achieved with two separate textboxes.

Comment: Side note: have you tried to use what you are trying to build? Sounds like very painful control to type in (also you may not really care about users and just want to practice in low level control stuff, which is fine too)

Comment: No I haven't. It may not be as painful as you think: when the user types onto the textbox while the cursor is placed onto the static part, it will move the cursor to the end of the static text. Is that what you meant by painful?

Comment: @LouisTakePILLz it's painful when you try prevent user from **selecting** all the text and **pressing** the **delete** key. Of course you can prevent it but the **correct** solution is only editable text is clear, the readonly text should be there wihout being removed.

Comment: @King King Selecting all the text? I never talked about selection, the static text is supposed to be "readonly". Also, I don't get what you mean with that "correct solution", would you mind re-explaining?